# Why does grep return no results (list all files in directory)

Tags: linux, grep, zsh

I'm trying to count all files in a directory that match a pattern, recursively, using `ls`:

```
ls -R | grep *.{cpp,h} | wc
```

However, I get:

> zsh: no matches found: *.cpp

`ls -R` does return results, though:

> $ ls -R 
>   CMakeLists.txt cmake          src
>
> ./cmake:
>   Modules    SUBS.cmake
>
> ./cmake/Modules:
>   FindGecode.cmake
>
> ./src:
>   A1_examples.h Sub1Main.cpp  Sudoku.cpp    Sudoku.h      nQueens.cpp

Why doesn't `grep` find the `*.cpp` files that `ls -R` returns?

Edit: I'm also pretty sure that `ls -R | grep *.{cpp,h} | wc` is not the best way to do this, because of the way that `ls` returns multiple results on single lines, but I'm not certain.

Comment: what kind of syntax is {cpp,h} ?

Comment: As to the multiline:  compare `ls` to `ls | cat` sometime.  `ls` is smart enough to do multicolumn only when reporting directly (or when told to do so explicitly); it assumes `-C` for terminals and `-1` for pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making two different mistakes that play together.  First, you need to quote the pattern sent to `grep`, otherwise the shell will expand it first.  (That's where the error message comes from.)  Second, `grep` does not accept shell globs, it wants a regex.

`zsh` being what it is, you may want to say

```
$ ls **/*.{cpp,h} | wc -l
```

instead, using a `zsh`-style recursive glob.  If you want to use the other one, it's

```
$ ls -R | egrep '\.(cpp|h)$' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just been trying to get it working with plain `grep` rather than `egrep` (because I didn't know what the differences were). For my future reference: `egrep` is `grep -E` (enabled use of extended regular expressions; the brackets in the answer only work if the regular expression is an extended one).

Comment: `egrep` is the original; `grep -E` is a GNUism.  Also a GNUism is that you can use escaping instead:  `grep '\.\(cpp\|h\)'`.  Neither is portable.