# Recursively count files matching pattern in directory in zsh

Tags: zsh

How do I recursively count all files of a certain type in `zsh`?

There are quite a few methods to do this (helpful SuperUser questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/198817/recursively-count-all-the-files-in-a-directory) give pointers), but few `zsh`-specific methods.

This follows [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/410286/why-does-grep-return-no-results-list-all-files-in-directory/410288#410288) - several `zsh`-specific solutions have been given to me, so I will [record them here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) in case anybody else ever wants to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zsh`-specific feature is zsh globbing; I don't fully understand it, but these work.

1. `$ a=( **/*.(cpp|h)(.) ); print $#a`

   Will count all files ending in `.cpp` and `.h` recursively from the current directory, then print the result as a single number.
2. From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/410288/119064), I can also use:

   `$ ls **/*.{cpp,h} | wc -l`

The `zsh` specific part, then, is the expansion of `**/*.{cpp,h}` to match files ending in `.cpp` and `.h`. I haven't yet found any (simple) comprehensive of zsh globbing that I've been able to understand (although [this explains](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/globbing-wildcard-characters-with-zsh/6140012) the use of `**/*.{a,b}` fairly well).

Comment: `zsh` kinda defies "simple"; it's got a lot of functionality and it's hard to describe most of it simply.

Comment: explanation of 1. `( */.(cpp|h)(.) )` sets a as an array of all files matching the glob, and `$#a` gives its size

Answer (score 1):

To count no matches correctly: `a=( */.(cpp|h)(.N) ); print $#a`

To avoid leaking the variable: `local -a a; a=( */.(cpp|h)(.N) ); print $#a`